# How to put condition in django signals

Tags: django, django-models

I working on hospital management system.In this user first register as Doctor or patient for that i had userprofileinfo model.I also have profile model for the user which is create as soom as user register,here problem arise i want profile is only created if user type is pateint but i dont know how to check  condition in django Signals. i tried some way but it show following error

```
type object 'UserProfileInfo' has no attribute 'instance'
```

files:-
[userprofileinfo.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAOvK.png)
[patientprofile.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOnTy.png)

Edit :- On one of the good suggestion i made changes such that When user is registered as Doctor is_staff is set true but when registered as patient is_staff is false but when i used it in signals it always return false .Point to be noted that in django admin site is_staff is ticked for doctor and super

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_profile_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):


        if created:
            if instance.is_staff:
                PateintProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
                instance.pateintprofile.save()
```

Comment: Please upload your code. Not image!!! Upload your problem with proper indentation

Answer (score 0):

> Try in to do in signal
>   You should check condition with **instance which is created**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_profile_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.user_type=="2": # Check here
             PateintProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
             instance.pateintprofile.save()
```

try this stuff and let me know

Comment: No Success its shows an error:-     'User' object has no attribute 'user_type'

Comment: 'User' object has no attribute 'user_type'

Comment: i also tried   this  [ instance.userprofileinfo.user_type == "2"]  or [user.userprofileinfo.user_type == "2" ]

Comment: in this case you did access userprofile before creation you should check is_staff attribute for doctor and normal for patient so after creating user you check `instance.is_staff` is called doctor othewise patient so you need to check on when user created

Comment: before creation of userprofile you never access it and through the error

Comment: your error is saying user_type field is not inside User model cause it is inside UserProfileInfo but your instance here is User. What it you make user choose between patient or doctor when the user registers. That way you can get user_type before creating the profile and than you can create the profile if the user is patient.

Comment: yes you should add some check box or select option when user register if user chose doctor at view side `user.is_staff=True` so when then save you user after save signal will call in that you check `instance.is_staff` it means user want to be doctor other wise patient if he or she is doctor then it's `user_type =="1"` means doctor other in else `user_ type="2"` patient so after this you will create as per user choice other wise not chance because before create any userprofile of that specific user you would not access their any properties or attributes so think on this might be helpfull to you

Comment: I had done the changes and when user Registered as Doctor it is set is_staff true,But when i access it in signals it always return False whether if it is Doctor or pateint  . point to be noted in django admin is_staff is set true only for Doctor